# regex grab a word

Tags: regex

i'm trying to grab a regex from source, but only name from this type.

```
"name":"HELP-PERP","posOnly":false,"price":40.3,"priceIncrement":0.01,"quote":null,"quoteV":73851918.483,"restricted":false,"sizeIncrement":0.01,"type":"future",
```

So i got here `\b(\w*-PERP\w*)\b`

This grabs the word `HELP-PERP` but duplicates it, so i'm trying to grab that word that matches the type `=future`.

Grab help-perp that is in the same line with type":"future".

Total nub at this, i've tried several things on regex101 and can't come up :(

Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you need to obtain and why?

Comment: There's a list with -PERP and it has over 40 words word-PERP, and the regex i tried grabs duplicates, so i'm trying to grab it just once and extract it from the type=future only, and with that will help me make a list of the ...-PERP i need.

Comment: I understand you are using JavaScript, and the duplication comes up due to the capturing group, you just need to use `/\b\w*-PERP\w*\b/g`. If you need to check for the `type":"future"` presence on the line, use `/\b\w*-PERP\w*\b(?=.*type":"future")/g`. Now, is it all you need? Sorry, it is still unclear.

Comment: Yes, Perfect...Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
/\w*-PERP\w*\b(?=.*type":"future")/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nu1nEC/2).

*Details*

- `\w*-PERP\w*` - zero or more word chars, `-PERP`, and again zero or more chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=.*type":"future")` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`) and then a `type":"future"` string.